# How to let Django know when to Insert or Update with overrided save()

Tags: python, django

I want to do some piece of code when my model inserts, and when it updates another piece of code. I have this model with an overrided save() method. The idea is to execute that code only for insert. How can I tell django when to insert, when to update and what code to execute for each one?

```py
class Galeria(models.Model):
    galeriaid = models.AutoField(db_column='GaleriaID', primary_key=True)   
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)   
    ruta = models.FileField(db_column='Ruta', max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
def save( self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    super( Galeria, self ).save( *args, **kwargs )

    ruta = self.ruta
    if ruta:
        oldfile = self.ruta.name
        dot = oldfile.rfind( '.' )
        newfile = str( self.pk ) + oldfile[dot:]

        if newfile != oldfile:
            self.ruta.storage.delete( newfile )                
            if newfile.endswith(".jpg"):
                self.ruta.storage.save( "imagenes/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                self.ruta.name = "imagenes/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile)
            elif newfile.endswith(".mp4"):
                self.ruta.storage.save( "videos/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile), ruta )
                self.ruta.name = "videos/" + str(timezone.now().strftime("%Y/%m/")) + str(newfile)
            else:
                self.ruta.storage.save( newfile, ruta )
                self.ruta.name = newfile 
                self.ruta.close()
                self.ruta.storage.delete( oldfile )

    super( Galeria, self ).save( *args, **kwargs )
```

Comment: Do you know which function is  called where? Or do you want save() function to figure out that the model is updated (automatically)?

Comment: @SumitBadsara I need to execute a function when save() (but only if insert) and then if save() is update then execute vanilla save() of django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use django post_save [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) for this model